# Python send_keys(Keys.TAB) types a symbol "E004" (Selenium/Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium

When I use this code in Python to send the TAB key it doesn't Tab but instead types the symbol in the below picture. Is there a different way to do this that will tab and not type the symbol?

```
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

[image]

Comment: The `send_keys` method for alerts try to send text, so it writes the key code for TAB. You could try to use instead the `authenticate(username, password)` method for alerts http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert.authenticate

Comment: I tried that but I get an error saying no json could be decoded